# "Authentication servers are down, please try again later." vanilla 1.8 MineOS

Tags: server, minecraft

I have had a MineOS setup using the pre-packaged Turnkey bundle on a dedicated system and it worked at first, but recently the system kicked everyone off the server. Any attempt to reconnect give the message: "Authentication servers are down, try again later." and 4 days later, same issue.

From what I can tell this means that the server can't verify my user ID with Mojang's servers for some reason. I checked and there are no disruptions on Mojang's servers, so it must be my system. I tried disabling online-mode and it said "You are not whitelisted on this server." and still wouldn't let any one in. Im thinking this is an error in the firewall configuration but I dont know how or where to start with that. I have already verified that my router is not blocking access to Mojang's servers so it must be within my system configurations somewhere.

What confuses me is why it worked at first and then quit seemingly at random. Any thoughts on what is causing this and how to fix it? thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with *programming* with or for Minecraft.

Comment: so what would it be then? its not a mojang error or it wouldn't let me in to other servers. the issue is isolated to this server machine only so therefore thats where the issue must be.

Comment: Perhaps you might consider it to be some sort of … [SF].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the dns server had gotten messed up when changing a static ip. fixed that and everything started working again.